# Database inventory system design SQL

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am rebuilding a current inventory application. And I am looking for improvements.

The current situation:
I have a product that can be stored on several locations (1 or many). Even, 1 location can hold multiple (different) products.

So I have this design:

```
product:
 - id
 - description

location
 - id
 - name

stock:
 -id
 -product_id
 -location_id
 -amount
```

That is what I want. But now the main issue. Calculating the total stock per product takes to long. I have around 20K products and 18K locations. So I thought I can save the total stock at the product table. Is this a bad approach?

Also, I want to save where stock is coming from and to which location it is shipped. So I want to make 2 tables for it. One for incoming and one for outgoing stock. Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

> So I thought I can save the total stock at the product table. Is this a bad approach?

Yes, this is generally a bad approach.  Instead, you should just calculate the value for a given product:

```
select sum(s.amount)
from stock s
where s.product_id = @product_id;
```

With an index on `stock(product_id, amount)`, this should have very good performance.

Why is duplicating the information at the `product` level bad?  The problem is maintaining the data.  You would have to have triggers for `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s on the `stock` table.  This is cumbersome to maintain.

Under some circumstances, such an approach might be necessary.  But with only 20,000 rows, you should be able to optimize the database without resorting to triggers.

Comment: Since product_id is not unique on the stock table, I would just "include" the amount field, rather than making it part of the index, if the database supports that.  That will save a bit of work when updating the index.